# display large string into multiple pages in single activity

Tags: android

I am very new to android development. I am trying to create a simple two activities based ebbok type application where `activity1` is table of content and `activity2` displays the details. I have a listview in Activity1 where I list the table of content. On clicking any specific content, I load `activity2`. In `onCreate` of `activity2`, I load the content into a string(from a txt file in assets). and display that in textView (as defined in `activity2`.xml). So far so good. The challenge now is to display the content page-wise because, as of now all of my string gets loaded into a single page in `activity2`. So I added two buttons at the bottom of `activity2` (defined that in `activity2.xml`). My planned logic now is

1. get the screen height (I could get that)
2. get the botton height and substract 2) from 1). Now I cannot do this becuase I cannot get button height in `onCreate` of `Activity2`
3. and then find how much text I can fit in one page, find number of pages accordingly, use a page index and using a page delimiter, keep loading remaining text into next pages when user clicks "next" button.

So i need help with 
-how to get button width as I have mentioned in 2) 
-and any sample code you can share to perform 3) above will also help me.

any help here from any one of you experts out there will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Using Fragements will Solve your problem.

[**Fragements**](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) :

A Fragment represents a behavior or a portion of user interface in an Activity. You can combine multiple fragments in a single activity to build a multi-pane UI and reuse a fragment in multiple activities. You can think of a fragment as a modular section of an activity, which has its own lifecycle, receives its own input events, and which you can add or remove while the activity is running (sort of like a "sub activity" that you can reuse in different activities).

For example, a news application can use one fragment to show a list of articles on the left and another fragment to display an article on the right—both fragments appear in one activity, side by side, and each fragment has its own set of lifecycle callback methods and handle their own user input events. Thus, instead of using one activity to select an article and another activity to read the article, the user can select an article and read it all within the same activity

For More About fragements just go through [this link](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html).
Hope it will help you.

Comment: I had evaluated the option os using Fragments. But i realised I will just be saving one activity by doing that becuase anyway I have just two activities in my app. Also I wanted table of content to be a separate activity. Even if I had been using Fragements, I would still had faced this problem of displaying a long string into multiple pages and I would have had to put some buttons(for page navigation) in my fragment.

Comment: if you have very long string you can put all in a scrollview.it will scroll through that fragement only.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a much efficient way to display a long string across number of pages.                 -I display the long text into the text view and disable scrolling                                    -I then find out the lines in the layout and lines on single screen, hence I know how many screens(pages) will the long string span across                                                         -Then whenever user clicks a button to go to next page or swipes screen to go to the next page then I use TexView.scrollTo() function to move to number of lines(as many on a screen) forward. So it becomes as good as moving to next page